# Разность списков в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

В процессе выполнения одной задачи на Python возник вот какой вопрос. В общем, есть список целых чисел, например list1 = [1,2,4,6,8,10,2]; и второй список из двух случайных элементов list1,
Выбираю так `pair = random.sample(list1,2)` Пусть pair окажется [2,4]
Task: из list1 убрать элементы из списка pair, но убрать по одному элементу, т.е чтобы вторая 2 в list1 осталась. 
Пробовал так: list1 = [x for x in list1 if x not in pair], но такой способ удаляет все двойки и четвёрки.

Answer (score 2):

Удалить каждый элемент второго списка из первого:

```
for num in pair:
    list1.remove(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Порядок элементов в списке важен? Если для ваших целей порядком можно пренебречь, то имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону `collections.Counter`

По крайне мере на больших списках точно имеет смысл использовать его, т.к. это более производительный способ.

```
from collections import Counter
import random


list1 = [1,2,4,6,8,10,2]
pair = random.sample(list1,2)

cntr = Counter(list1)

cntr.subtract(pair)

list1 = list(cntr.elements())

print(list1)
```

Впрочем, если список всегда небольшой и вы всегда будете удалять из него только по два элемента, то лучше использовать вариант Эникейщика.